# How to get this geometric value?

Tags: geometry, circles, pythagorean-triples

I'm designing a mechanical setup to operate x-ray tubes for medical purposes. For this, electrons circle around in a round tube and collide with a target somewhen.
Afterwards, they'll produce photons which impinge on multiple detectors in a certain distance `a`.

Now the thing is, these tubes are individual and I have to shift them vertically to align them with the optical axis so as much as possible photons can impinge on the detectors. There are several ways to figure out to do this and I've concluded that the most efficient way is to use geometrical information. I had some methods in mind but up to now I wasn't able to really use them to determine the distance `c` to shift the so-called target.

Is it possible with these given distances to calculate the desired distance `c`?

[image: img]

Comment: What’s b in your question?

Comment: the target has to be shifted about the distance c so to center with the optical axis. Then most of the photons will hit the detectors centrally. Ah sorry, I misread your question. b is the distance between the target and the detectors, it is actually exactly 1 m.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question : where the optical axis you mention is situated on your figure ? What is the disk useful for ? Whether or not the little blue disk is the center of the disk, therefore with radius b , etc.

Comment: There is no distance determining location of horizontal axis from which $c$ is measured, so answer is definitely No.

Comment: See picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/e62yy.png You need add data or some requirements (for example $a_1=d_1=d_2$)

Comment: @JeanMarie The little blue center is not the center of the disk. The circle is to represent the x-ray tubes which are circle-shaped.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thanks for the formulas, I'll have a closer look at them!